# Не обновляются статические файлы

Tags: django, pycharm

Учусь взаимодействию PyCharm и Django. На днях полностью скопировал весь проект из Ubuntu под Windows. Всё работает, но при изменении статических файлов (напр-р стилей) изменения не происходят (на Ubuntu всё работало, настройки для статических файлов прописаны). Самое интересное, что при удалении папки со статическими файлами (в моём случае static), файлы со стилями всё равно откуда-то подхватываются. Не знаю что делать.

Вот настройки прописанные в settings.py

```
DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'test_app',)

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
#'/var/www/static/',
)
```

Вот это в urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url('', include('test_app.urls')),)

if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Папка static находится в корне проекта.

Comment: Сервер просто физически не может читать файлы, если вы удалили каталог с ними. Поэтому могу предположить, что это всего лишь браузер закешировал вашу статику. После перезапуска браузера думаю вы увидите то, что должны.

Comment: Похоже на то. После перезапуска браузера все изменения отобразились. Спасибо, а то больше часа пытался найти проблему там, где её нет.

Comment: Если комментарий оказался вам полезен, его тоже можно плюсануть)